# In Vim, how can I delete everything between quotes including the quotes?

Tags: vim

For example, in the following:

```
Testing "deleting" within quotes
```

With the cursor inside of deleting, how can I delete the text within the quotes and include the quotes, leaving:

```
Testing within quotes
```

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843099/in-vim-how-can-i-delete-everything-between-quotes-including-the-quotes

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can use the following sequence to delete everything including the quotes:

```
da"
```

Keep in mind this only works on a single line, and will remove any trailing spaces after the last quote.

As pointed out by @James in the comments below, you can also use the *delete inside* sequence to delete the characters within the quotes without deleting the quotes:

```
di"
```

You can also use the *change inside* sequence to remove the characters and switch to insert mode, allowing you to easily replace text within quotes:

```
ci"
```

Comment: Fair enough, although I added this since it seems to be a common question for a beginner and it has not yet been asked or answered (although similar questions have been). It's typically easier to do a quick search than traverse the manual for a beginner (who might not know about Vim's `:help`). Feel free to edit the answer with your suggestions if you think that would be helpful.

Comment: Vim `:help` is only helpful if you already know what you are looking for. It is useful to have these operations documented somewhere where it is easy to find them.

Comment: Added point: You can also do this *without* deleting the quotes with `di"`. Very useful, especially with `ci"`

Comment: with mapping like `nnoremap va" ?"<CR>v/"<CR>` there is a ability to select text in multiline

Comment: I know this is old, but comon. not everyone can find everything in the manual all the time. sometimes you *just* miss it. Also, Q&As like this make searching for answers easier.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Yeah this answer was at the top of my google query which saved me the hassle. So it wasn't all for nothing.

@blacktide Is it possible to get `da"` to work across multiple lines?

Comment: A similar motion, `ca"` to remove the quotes and content in between them and change to insert mode. Good for changing things like `the "dog" is brown` to `the dog is brown`.

Comment: the JSON gods will appreciate the `ci"` much more

Comment: Well I prefer to google a question and get the result right away than having to read pages and pages of documentation. This kind of behaviour is the reason SO has the reputation it has...

Answer (score 39):

We can use

```
da"
```

for your case
or `di"` to delete ONLY the contents inside of ".

It is better to start with text-objects. Writing as an answer for completeness.
Excerpt from `:h text-objects`, given below, suggest two forms `i` and `a`

> This is a series of commands that can only be used while in Visual mode or
> after an operator.  The commands that start with "a" select "a"n object
> including white space, the commands starting with "i" select an "inner" object
> without white space, or just the white space.  Thus the "inner" commands                                                                    always select less text than the "a" commands.

text-objects are useful to **other character pair like `(), {}, etc`**. For example, it is useful while changing

```
if ( i == true ) {
}
```

to

```
if (_) {
}
```

by using `ci(` or `ci)`.

Comment: How to delete content in quotes start from current position? For example "abc|de", "|" is the position of the cursor, to delete the "de" only.

Comment: It should be more than one word are enclosed in quotes, I just gave a bad example.

Comment: How about `dt"`?

Answer (score 3):

Keep your cursor in first quotes and press d, then type /"/e
It should delete the content between both double quotes as well as quotes.
This is applicable for muliple lines as well.

Another way:
Keep the cursor in first quotes and type df"
It will also delete the text inside quotes and quotes too! Not applicable for multiple lines.

In both the ways, you execute commands in normal mode.

Comment: These methods don't work when another double quotes is present in between these quotes.